# Timestamps with different timezones in the same pandas DatetimeIndex object?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, pytz

Is it possible to convert a pd.DatetimeIndex consisting of timestamps in a single timezone to one where each timestamp has its own, in some cases distinct timezone?

Here is an example of what I would like to have:

type(df.index)

```
 pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

df.index[0]

```
Timestamp('2015-06-07 23:00:00+0100', tz='Europe/London')
```

df.index[1]

```
Timestamp('2015-06-08 00:01:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels')
```

Comment: pls show an example of what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* have an index contain `Timestamps` with different timezones. But you would have to explicity construct it as an `Index`.

```
In [33]: pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('2015-06-07 23:00:00+0100', tz='Europe/London'),pd.Timestamp('2015-06-08 00:01:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels')],dtype='object')
Out[33]: Index([2015-06-07 23:00:00+01:00, 2015-06-08 00:01:00+02:00], dtype='object')

In [34]: list(pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('2015-06-07 23:00:00+0100', tz='Europe/London'),pd.Timestamp('2015-06-08 00:01:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels')],dtype='object'))  
Out[34]: 
[Timestamp('2015-06-07 23:00:00+0100', tz='Europe/London'),
 Timestamp('2015-06-08 00:01:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels')]
```

This is a very odd thing to do, and completely non-performant. You generally want to have a *single* timezone represented (UTC or other). In 0.17.0, you can represent efficiently a single column with a timezone, so one way of accomplishing what I think your goal is to segregate the different timezones into different columns. See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#datetime-with-tz)

Comment: thanks @Jeff, I agree with your advice on avoiding localtime in the index whenever possible. however in some cases the scientific question we want to solve may relate to a phenomenon entrained to local-time. i've tried to come up with a specific example. could you pls have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201680/calculate-mean-sales-per-minute-accross-24-hour-cycles-as-per-local-time-hhmm

Comment: I'll respond on your other question. you simply keep the times in separate columns - you don't need to set as an index (or maybe u have utc for an index)

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy for it to not be an `Index`, but just a regular `Series` this should be OK:

```
pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2015-06-07 23:00:00+0100', tz='Europe/London'),
           pd.Timestamp('2015-06-08 00:01:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding timestamps with different timezones into the same `DatetimeIndex` automatically yields a `DatetimeIndex` with UTC as the default timezone. For example:

```
In [269]  index = pandas.DatetimeIndex([Timestamp('2015-06-07 23:00:00+0100')])

In [270]  index
Out[270]  DatetimeIndex(['2015-06-07 23:00:00+01:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]', freq=None)

In [271]  index2 = DatetimeIndex([Timestamp('2015-06-08 00:01:00+0200')])

In [272]  index2
Out[272]  DatetimeIndex(['2015-06-08 00:01:00+02:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]', freq=None)

In [273]  index.append(index2)  # returns single index containing both data
Out[273]  DatetimeIndex(['2015-06-07 22:00:00+00:00', '2015-06-07 22:01:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)
```

Notice how the result is a UTC `DatetimeIndex` with the correct UTC timestamps preserved.

Similarly:

```
In [279]  pandas.to_datetime([Timestamp('2015-06-07 23:00:00+0100'), Timestamp('2015-06-08 00:01:00+0200')], utc=True)  # utc=True is needed
Out[279]  DatetimeIndex(['2015-06-07 22:00:00+00:00', '2015-06-07 22:01:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)
```

This is not a bad thing as you get to preserve the correct time while having the ability to use the indexing prowess of `DatetimeIndex` (e.g. slice by date range) and at the same time you can easily convert the timestamps to any other timezone (unless you really need to know the original timezone of each timestamp, then this won't be ideal).