# calculate mean sales per minute accross 24-hour cycles as per local-time (HH:MM)

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, pytz

In this example we have two days of data sampled at a resolution of 1min, giving us 2880 measurements. The measurements are collected across multiple timezones **sequentially**: the first 240 minutes in Europe/London and the remaining 2640 measurements in 'America/Los_Angeles'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range('2015-03-29 00:00','2015-03-30 23:59',freq='1min',tz='UTC')))
df.loc['2015-03-29 00:00':'2015-03-29 04:00','timezone']='Europe/London'
df.loc['2015-03-29 04:00':'2015-03-30 23:59','timezone']='America/Los_Angeles'
df['sales1']=np.random.random_integers(100,size=len(df))
df['sales2']=np.random.random_integers(10,size=len(df))
```

To calculate mean sales per minute (as per UTC time) in a 24-hour cycle across multiple days the following approach works nicely:

```
utc_sales=df.groupby([df.index.hour,df.index.minute]).mean()
utc_sales.set_index(pd.date_range("00:00","23:59", freq="1min").time,inplace=True)
```

This groupby approach can also be applied to calculate mean sales based on one of the other two timezones, say 'Europe/London'.

```
df['London']=df.index.tz_convert('Europe/London')
london_sales=df.groupby([df['London'].dt.hour,df['London'].dt.minute]).mean()
london_sales.set_index(pd.date_range("00:00","23:59", freq="1min").time,inplace=True)
```

However I'm struggling to come up with an efficient way of calculating mean sales per minute -as per localtime- in a 24-hour cycle. I attempted the same approach from above, however when multiple timezones are present in the same series, groupby reverts back to the index which is in utc.

```
def calculate_localtime(x):
    return pd.to_datetime(x.name,unit='s').tz_convert(x['timezone'])
df['localtime']=df.apply(calculate_localtime,axis=1)
local_sales=df.groupby([df['localtime'].dt.hour,df['localtime'].dt.minute]).mean()
local_sales.set_index(pd.date_range("00:00","23:59",freq="1min").time,inplace=True)
```

We can verify that local_sales are identical to utc_sales, and therefore this approach does not work.

```
In [8]: np.unique(local_sales == utc_sales)
Out[8]: array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

Could anyone recommend an approach suitable for large datatsets and multiple timezones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach to get what I think you want. This requires pandas 0.17.0

Create the data as you have aboe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.options.display.max_rows=12
np.random.seed(1234)
df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range('2015-03-29 00:00','2015-03-30 23:59',freq='1min',tz='UTC')))
df.loc['2015-03-29 00:00':'2015-03-29 04:00','timezone']='Europe/London'
df.loc['2015-03-29 04:00':'2015-03-30 23:59','timezone']='America/Los_Angeles'
df['sales1']=np.random.random_integers(100,size=len(df))
df['sales2']=np.random.random_integers(10,size=len(df))

In [79]: df
Out[79]: 
                                      timezone  sales1  sales2
2015-03-29 00:00:00+00:00        Europe/London      48       6
2015-03-29 00:01:00+00:00        Europe/London      84       1
2015-03-29 00:02:00+00:00        Europe/London      39       1
2015-03-29 00:03:00+00:00        Europe/London      54      10
2015-03-29 00:04:00+00:00        Europe/London      77       5
2015-03-29 00:05:00+00:00        Europe/London      25       9
...                                        ...     ...     ...
2015-03-30 23:54:00+00:00  America/Los_Angeles      77       8
2015-03-30 23:55:00+00:00  America/Los_Angeles      16       4
2015-03-30 23:56:00+00:00  America/Los_Angeles      55       3
2015-03-30 23:57:00+00:00  America/Los_Angeles      18       1
2015-03-30 23:58:00+00:00  America/Los_Angeles       3       2
2015-03-30 23:59:00+00:00  America/Los_Angeles      52       2

[2880 rows x 3 columns]
```

Pivot according to the timezone; this creates a multi-index with the timezone separated

```
    x = pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),values=['sales1','sales2'],index='index',columns='timezone').swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
    x.columns.names = ['timezone','sales']

In [82]: x
Out[82]: 
timezone                  America/Los_Angeles Europe/London America/Los_Angeles Europe/London
sales                                  sales1        sales1              sales2        sales2
index                                                                                        
2015-03-29 00:00:00+00:00                 NaN            48                 NaN             6
2015-03-29 00:01:00+00:00                 NaN            84                 NaN             1
2015-03-29 00:02:00+00:00                 NaN            39                 NaN             1
2015-03-29 00:03:00+00:00                 NaN            54                 NaN            10
2015-03-29 00:04:00+00:00                 NaN            77                 NaN             5
2015-03-29 00:05:00+00:00                 NaN            25                 NaN             9
...                                       ...           ...                 ...           ...
2015-03-30 23:54:00+00:00                  77           NaN                   8           NaN
2015-03-30 23:55:00+00:00                  16           NaN                   4           NaN
2015-03-30 23:56:00+00:00                  55           NaN                   3           NaN
2015-03-30 23:57:00+00:00                  18           NaN                   1           NaN
2015-03-30 23:58:00+00:00                   3           NaN                   2           NaN
2015-03-30 23:59:00+00:00                  52           NaN                   2           NaN

[2880 rows x 4 columns]
```

Create the groupers that we want to use, namely hours and minutes in the local zone. We are going to populate them according to the mask, IOW. where both sales1/sales2 are notnull, we will use the hours/minutes for that (local) zone

```
hours = pd.Series(index=x.index)
minutes = pd.Series(index=x.index)
for tz in ['America/Los_Angeles', 'Europe/London' ]:

   local = df.index.tz_convert(tz)
   x[(tz,'tz')] = local

   mask = x[(tz,'sales1')].notnull() & x[(tz,'sales2')].notnull()
   hours.iloc[mask.values] = local.hour[mask.values]
   minutes.iloc[mask.values] = local.minute[mask.values]

x = x.sortlevel(axis=1)
```

After the above. (Note this could be a bit simplified, meaning that we don't need to actually record the local timezone, just compute hours/minutes).

```
Out[84]: 
timezone                  America/Los_Angeles                                  Europe/London                                 
sales                                  sales1 sales2                        tz        sales1 sales2                        tz
index                                                                                                                        
2015-03-29 00:00:00+00:00                 NaN    NaN 2015-03-28 17:00:00-07:00            48      6 2015-03-29 00:00:00+00:00
2015-03-29 00:01:00+00:00                 NaN    NaN 2015-03-28 17:01:00-07:00            84      1 2015-03-29 00:01:00+00:00
2015-03-29 00:02:00+00:00                 NaN    NaN 2015-03-28 17:02:00-07:00            39      1 2015-03-29 00:02:00+00:00
2015-03-29 00:03:00+00:00                 NaN    NaN 2015-03-28 17:03:00-07:00            54     10 2015-03-29 00:03:00+00:00
2015-03-29 00:04:00+00:00                 NaN    NaN 2015-03-28 17:04:00-07:00            77      5 2015-03-29 00:04:00+00:00
2015-03-29 00:05:00+00:00                 NaN    NaN 2015-03-28 17:05:00-07:00            25      9 2015-03-29 00:05:00+00:00
...                                       ...    ...                       ...           ...    ...                       ...
2015-03-30 23:54:00+00:00                  77      8 2015-03-30 16:54:00-07:00           NaN    NaN 2015-03-31 00:54:00+01:00
2015-03-30 23:55:00+00:00                  16      4 2015-03-30 16:55:00-07:00           NaN    NaN 2015-03-31 00:55:00+01:00
2015-03-30 23:56:00+00:00                  55      3 2015-03-30 16:56:00-07:00           NaN    NaN 2015-03-31 00:56:00+01:00
2015-03-30 23:57:00+00:00                  18      1 2015-03-30 16:57:00-07:00           NaN    NaN 2015-03-31 00:57:00+01:00
2015-03-30 23:58:00+00:00                   3      2 2015-03-30 16:58:00-07:00           NaN    NaN 2015-03-31 00:58:00+01:00
2015-03-30 23:59:00+00:00                  52      2 2015-03-30 16:59:00-07:00           NaN    NaN 2015-03-31 00:59:00+01:00

[2880 rows x 6 columns]
```

This uses the new representation for timezones (in 0.17.0).

```
In [85]: x.dtypes
Out[85]: 
timezone             sales 
America/Los_Angeles  sales1                                float64
                     sales2                                float64
                     tz        datetime64[ns, America/Los_Angeles]
Europe/London        sales1                                float64
                     sales2                                float64
                     tz              datetime64[ns, Europe/London]
dtype: object
```

Results

```
x.groupby([hours,minutes]).mean()

timezone America/Los_Angeles        Europe/London       
sales                 sales1 sales2        sales1 sales2
0  0                    62.5    5.5            48      6
   1                    52.0    7.0            84      1
   2                    89.0    3.5            39      1
   3                    67.5    6.5            54     10
   4                    41.0    5.5            77      5
   5                    81.0    5.5            25      9
...                      ...    ...           ...    ...
23 54                   76.5    4.5           NaN    NaN
   55                   37.5    5.0           NaN    NaN
   56                   60.5    8.0           NaN    NaN
   57                   87.5    7.0           NaN    NaN
   58                   77.5    6.0           NaN    NaN
   59                   31.0    5.5           NaN    NaN

[1440 rows x 4 columns]
```